# Why did git show me this conflict when both the files were same?

Tags: git

This was the only conflict which I got when I did `$ git stash pop`
Its the last line of the file and both of which didn't have any newline in end.

[image: Same line but still shows conflict]

Is this something I don't know about git or is it some bug.
Git version 1.7.12

Comment: It should actually be EOF I guess.

Comment: There could be any whitespace.

Comment: No there isn't, I checked. The cursor doesn't go beyond the 'd' in both lines and also this is vimdiff it highlights the whitespaces.

Answer (score 2):

It seems consistent with '[git: merge conflicts over newline at end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355199/git-merge-conflicts-over-newline-at-end-of-file)', and typical when the setting `core.autocrlf` is set to `false` (which I recommend), instead of '`native`'.
Note that a merge will not ignore those eol differences (see "[Is it possible for git-merge to ignore line-ending differences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861995/is-it-possible-for-git-merge-to-ignore-line-ending-differences)").

If you want those eol conversion done for you automaticaly, then you could consider a `.gitattributes` settings, as described in "[Distributing git configuration with the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2354278/6309)".

Comment: Other cause for file modification: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13121378/6309 (but encoding should impact *all* lines of the file, not just the last one)