# Changing one character in a file leads to MSysGit thinking the whole file has changed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, git, version-control, line-endings

I have a git repository containing C# code, and I'm running `MSysGit` on Windows.

`core.autocrlf` is turned on, and I'm using the `.gitattributes` from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170961/whats-the-best-crlf-handling-strategy-with-git), and I "renormalised" my repo as mentioned at the bottom of [this Github guide](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings).

Now for *some* of the *.cs* files in my repository, if I change even one character, `MSysGit` thinks the whole file has changed.

I cloned the repository fresh. I tried editing the file first in Visual Studio, but then I tried opening it in [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) which shows me line ending and tab characters, and also I trust it not to do anything weird to the file (like change the encoding).

So, I clone the repository fresh:

```
$ git clone git clone git@git.assembla.com:my-repo.v2.git
$ cd my-repo/
```

I check the repository and the file:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
$ git diff path/to/myfile.cs
$
```

I open the file in SciTE (note that the line endings are `CRLF` and there are no tabs):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
...
```

and change one character (and note that `CRLF` and no tabs are still true):

```
using System;
!using System.Collections.Generic;
...
```

and now git thinks everything's changed:

```
$ git diff path/to/myfile.cs
diff --git a/path/to/myfile.cs b/Dpath/to/myfile.cs
--- a/path/to/myfile.cs
+++ b/path/to/myfile.cs
@@ -1,116 +1,116 @@
-<U+FEFF>using System;
-using System.Collections.Generic;
-using System.Linq;
-using System.Text;
-using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;
-using DataModel.Models;
-using DataModel.Mappers.Interfaces;
-using System.Data.Common;
-using System.Data;
...
```

A normal diff program doesn't think the two files are so different, and `git diff` on Unix doesn't think they're too different, but `msysgit` does.

Anyone ever encounter this before or have any ideas?

Comment: the problem was fixed when I restarted my computer. *sigh*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things that can make Git show the entire file as changed:

- Line endings -- but you said you checked these and they're the same;
- Indentation -- VS (especially if you have some extensions installed) might change the indentation from tabs to spaces or vice-versa. You can check this with "Show Whitespace" (Ctrl-R, Ctrl-W in VS or the relevant option in your differ).
- Encoding -- if VS decides to re-encode the file in some different encoding (e.g. UTF16) it might show up as entirely changed although the textual representation would look the same.

Comment: My first thought was the line endings, but given that's been checked the next in line will be the tabs/spaces issue for indentations.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be tabs/spaces. How can I check encoding? Although from an earlier experience I had, UTF-16 encoding is treated as binary by git, which my files aren't.

Comment: I rewrote the question after some investigation

Comment: Try to ask Git's diff to ignore whitespace and see what you get. Alternatively, try to ask another differ to not ignore whitespace and see if you get something different.

Comment: The problem was fixed when I restarted my computer. *sigh*.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. We had the exact same problem, and it turned out to be automatic conversion of tabs to spaces in Visual Studio.