# git rebase cut code at the end of file

Tags: git, github

When rebasing

`git rebase upstream/develop`

git cut conflict files ... not all but always at the end of rebasing

[image]

Please help me to solve this

for example here is enouther cutted code:

`CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in code/client/js/resident/controllers/faq.js`

```js
angular.module('smartnest.resident.index')

  .controller('ResidentFaqController', ['$scope', 'faqs', function($scope, faqs) {

    $scope.faqs = faqs;

<<<<<<<
```

Comment: Please post text as *text* and not as images. Images can't be searched.

Comment: See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355199/git-merge-conflicts-over-newline-at-end-of-file although there is no accepted answer there